# Rails 5 - Is there a way to convert if statement to controller logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an if statement in a loop that only displays posts from users followers:

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <% if post.user.following?(current_user) && current_user.following?(post.user) %>
            <%= post.body %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

And this is my controller code for that loop:

```
@posts = Post.where('created_at >= :one_day_ago', one_day_ago: Time.now - 24.hours).order("created_at DESC")
```

Is there a way to get the if statement into my controller code?

Comment: Can you post your `following?` methods? IMO, I think a scope on the post model that takes an argument of the `current_user` in addition to your query that you have in your controller. This way you can clean up your controller and reduce the logic on the view like you want. ie `@posts = Post.by_followings(current_user)` and then perform your checks in there maybe?

Comment: `following?` is the method provided by the acts_as_follower gem [link](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower). I'm sure it's an easy fix but I'm just a beginner so is it possible if you could show what you would do in both the controller, view, model etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the if statement into my controller code?

Sure, it could look like this:

```
@posts = Post.where('created_at >= :one_day_ago', one_day_ago: Time.now - 24.hours).order("created_at DESC")
@posts = @posts.filter do |post|
  post.user.following?(current_user) && current_user.following?(post.user)
end
```

Then in your view you just render the filtered posts:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You also want to eager_load/include posts' users too (to avoid N+1 queries, at least in this part), but that's out of scope here.

Comment: And to further improve efficiency you'll want to bypass acts_as_follower api and join its `follow` table directly, to filter all users in the database. This is _super_ out of scope. :)